# Extjs grid cant get store buffered working

Tags: extjs

I have a large dataset (over 80k records). So I am trying to implement buffer but I couldn't get it work.  If I include buffered configuration I am getting error object doesn't support this property. When I remove it, works ok but of course it takes forever to load the data.

Here is my code

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false
});

Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer', 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature']);

Ext.define('Borrower', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Num',
        type:
            'string'
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function () {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: false,
        model: 'Borrower',
        pageSize: 100,
        buffered: true, // getting error object doestn support this property in extjs-all-debug.js
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'borrBuff.xsp/byName',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            }
        }

    });

    var filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false,
        local: true
    };

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'testgrid',
        store: store,
        features: [filters],
        plugins: 'bufferedrenderer',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Borr Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            filterable: true
        }, {
            text: 'Number',
            dataIndex: 'Num'
        }]
    });

})
```

Opening the grid in a window on button click

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('testgrid');
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    title: 'Grid Filters Example',
    height: 400,
    width: 700,
    modal: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: grid
}).show();
grid.getStore().load();
```

Just couldnt figure out what I am doing wrong. Appreciate any help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Are you using ExtJS 4.2?

Comment: Yes. One more thing i noticed while trying to debug the error is on line filterBy(). If i remove filter, no longer see the error. But the buffer still doesnt work and i do need filter, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to fetch all the data from server?

I'd recommend using [data paging](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/paging.html) with all the pros, speed being the first one (and some cons too). If you choose to use an infinite grid, it will work well. In fact the basic idea behind infinite grid is [fetching data in chunks](http://www.sencha.com/blog/infinite-grid-scrolling-in-ext-js-4/) (data paging in other words).

Filtering works without any problems with this scenario, see [sample](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/infinite-scroll-with-filter.html). It's usually handled by server, which is built to do this kind of tasks.

Comment: I am presenting this as a dialog list where user can choose multiple items.  Infinite scrolling looks better for this purpose than paging.  Besides i am not sure if filtering works on the entire store with paging.

Comment: @lense: I clarified my answer with your new inputs.

Comment: Thanks Peter Ivan, I am looking for column filtering.  But this example is useful i will try it out.